# Chrome will not INSERT INTO table, works fine on IE

Tags: php, mysql, google-chrome, sql-insert

I am using this PHP to insert data into mysql. Everything works find on IE, but database does not update when using chrome. Has anyone else had this problem?

```
<?php
include_once ("php_includes/db_conx.php");

mysqli_select_db($db_conx , "reservation_test") or die('Error: '.mysql_error());

$name = $_POST['name'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

$result = $db_conx->query ("INSERT INTO cid2064 (name, company, email, phone) VALUES ('$name', '$company', '$email', '$phone');");
echo "$name You have Successfully Registered";
?>
```

Comment: The browser should have no effect on your interaction with the database. You're also mixing mysql and mysqli. That won't work. You're also using mysqli incorrectly. This code shouldn't be working at all. Plus you're also wide open to sql injections. You should consider rewriting this code from scratch.

Comment: Besides the potential SQL injection problem you have, what error are you getting?  Also, what do you see when debugging your request on the client side, using Chrome's Dev Tools or IE's F12, or on the server if you debug your PHP code?

Comment: In spite of the mentioned issues you have in your SQL commands, could you provide what error does it show? I wondered to know what's your html form to submit?

Comment: not worried about security at the moment..I just wanted to get the mechanics down. Apparently I don't even have that. however the code does work. and I removed a line of style code that was above it, and now it works on chrome...I am very new to this. and that seems to be my problem most of the time mixing mysql and mysqli. The problem is most thing researched via google do not differentiate between the two. I am assuming mysqli is fairly new, and not much info on the google...lol

Comment: it didnt show an error. It said successful, but when database was checked nothing was inserted

Comment: No the style code was not effecting it. I don't know? It seems to be working now for some reason..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a cache problem, as the browser has no effect on script running. Clear your browser cache, it might do the trick.